# Is there a way to update all documents in a collection with a random value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to increase a field in all documents with a random value and return the sum of all the increments.
I made it work by iterating through all collection but obviously it is very slow.

```
const earnMoneyForUsers = async () => {
  let usersCursor = await User.find()
    .select({ name: 1, weeklyEarnedMoney: 1, totalEarnedMoney: 1 })
    .cursor()
  let totalEarnedMoney = 0

  await usersCursor.eachAsync((user) => {
    let earnedMoneyByUser = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    let collectedAmount = earnedMoneyByUser * 0.02

    user.weeklyEarnedMoney += earnedMoneyByUser - collectedAmount
    user.totalEarnedMoney += earnedMoneyByUser - collectedAmount
    totalEarnedMoney += earnedMoneyByUser - collectedAmount
    user.save()
  })

  return totalEarnedMoney
}
```

I tried updateMany also but it updates all values with same random value and I don't know how I can sum the increment?

```
const earnMoneyForUsers = async () => {
  await User.updateMany(
    {},
    { $inc: { weeklyEarnedMoney: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) } }
  )

  return ?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `$rand` aggregation operator, and do a pipeline update like the bellow, doing all the calculations in the database, without sending data to the application.

The bellow is a way to re-write your code in MQL

```
let earnedMoneyByUser = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)  
let collectedAmount = earnedMoneyByUser * 0.02  
user.weeklyEarnedMoney += earnedMoneyByUser - collectedAmount  
user.totalEarnedMoney += earnedMoneyByUser - collectedAmount
```

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6233efcdf7e3c64c6511e14b)

```js
update(
{},
[{"$set": 
   {"earnedMoneyByUser": {"$toInt": {"$multiply": [{"$rand": {}}, 100]}}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"collectedAmount": {"$multiply": ["$earnedMoneyByUser", 0.02]}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"weeklyEarnedMoney": 
     {"$add": 
       ["$weeklyEarnedMoney",
         {"$subtract": ["$earnedMoneyByUser", "$collectedAmount"]}]}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"totalEarnedMoney": 
     {"$add": 
       ["$weeklyEarnedMoney",
         {"$subtract": ["$earnedMoneyByUser", "$collectedAmount"]}]}}}],
{"multi": true})
```

Comment: It distributes money to all players perfectly with updateMany your code only updated the first document in the collection with update(). But there is a problem say I have 10k users. I want to sum all the collected amount and return it. I have another collection named 'Leaderboard' and it has a field prizePool. I want to add total collected amount to prize pool. Thanks for the help.